# Building inline if(syntax) or (syntax)

Tags: php, if-statement, inline

Am I building this inline if statement correctly:

```
$main = !empty($searchResults['main']) && !empty($searchResults['main']['feed']['entry']) ? $searchResults['main']['feed']['entry'] : null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first test is redundant.

```
$main = !empty($searchResults['main']['feed']['entry']) ? $searchResults['main']['feed']['entry'] : null;
```

will do fine

Comment: yea, thought so... that was just a test

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should wrap your stuff into `(value1 && value2) ? true : false`, but in general this should be correct.

Comment: no, because I need to return data not just Boolean values... tnx anyway

Comment: oh, you got me wrong. this meant to be:
`value1 = evaluate expression`,
`value2 = evaluate expression`, `true = return something if value1 and value2 evaluate to true`, `false = return something if value1 and value2 evaluate to false`

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do:
`$youtube = empty($searchResults['main']['feed']['entry']) ? NULL : $searchResults['main']['feed']['entry'];`

Comment: it's just that's how I built it, not going to change it now for every line (the order I mean)...